# Select an element based on the input element value in xml

Tags: java, xml, parsing

For example if we have a xml file like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <company>
    <staff id="1001">
        <firstname>yong</firstname>
        <lastname>mook kim</lastname>
        <nickname>mkyong</nickname>
        <salary>100000</salary>
    </staff>
    <staff id="2001">
        <firstname>low</firstname>
        <lastname>yin fong</lastname>
        <nickname>fong fong</nickname>
        <salary>200000</salary>
    </staff>
    </company>
```

i want to write a java method that returns a list of firstname, lastname, nickname where firstname like "low". And i want to print the result in a table format in html page. Please help me friends I am new to programming. I have large xml file with more than 40,000 lines and nearly 500Mb of size. How can I query that file like we do from a database?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should start looking at XPaths: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/xpath.html
This should allow you to "query" your file, using all the filters you want.

Comment: I tried to find the solution but none explained in detail. it says for  expression = "/company/staff[@id='1001']"; but i want to get         expression = "/company/staff[@firstname='low']"; and print id, first name, last name, nickname, salary for first name like low. every one explaining by attribute but not in this kind of scenario. so please some one help me get this.